# Gradient Descent with Momentum Working Worse than Normal Gradient Descent

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, gradient-descent

I am currently doing the deeplearning.ai specialization by Andrew Ng. In the second course he talks about the different techniques of we can use to optimize gradient descent. The particular video I watched was the video on Momentum with Gradient Descent.

So, after watching the video I started a new project and implemented gradient descent(GD) without momentum and got an accuracy of 85%. I then, implemented momentum and got an accuracy of 62%.

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. I implemented the same algorithm as shown in the video. I'm guessing I missed some key points regarding the algorithm.

Also, can we use regularization with momentum? Because I tried with regularization and without regularization and both gave 62% accuracy.

Here are the graphs:

Without momentum(Accuracy 85%):
[image: Training Cost and Cross Validation Cost]

With momentum:
[image: Training Cost and Cross Validation Cost with Momentum]

Here's the Neural Network class: `>`https://pastebin.com/KwTU0XuP

Comment: I do **not** have experience in the field, but I *have* used optimization algorithms. If I understand what 'momentum' is for, then it should only influence the speed with which the result is obtained, not the precision, unless your functional shape is so strange that momentum can get the search point "stuck" in a "pit" in which it would not otherwise enter, or go "off the track". Imagine a skier of increasing weight going down a slope and ending up stuck in a gulley. If that is the case, you might try with a lower momentum parameter.

Comment: @LSerni That unfortunately does not work. I tried a bunch of different values and the graphs got worse.

Comment: With momentum, gradient descent may converge faster, but it doesn't guarantee that it will reach the global minimum. Here is an illustration: https://ikocabiyik.com/data-science/gradient-descent-with-momentum/